# Decompressing a file, download then remove

Tags: php, file, encryption, download, unzip

I have files that are Compressed,Encrypted.
The compressed files though have their original extensions. they dont have .zip or any other compression ext.

I have the following function that decrypts files then serves them for download.
So when I download files now I'm getting the decrypted files but still compressed.

I need help to implement decompression before download.

```
function Download($path,$type,$key,$iv){
    if($type=="File"){
        if (file_exists($path)) {
            $fileBuffer = file_get_contents($path);
            $iv = str_pad($iv, 16, "\0");
            $cipher = base64_decode($fileBuffer);
            $plain = openssl_decrypt($cipher, "AES-256-CBC", $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
            file_put_contents($path, $plain);

            header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
            header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($path).'"');
            header('Expires: 0');
            header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
            header('Pragma: public');
            header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($path));
            readfile($path);

            $fileBuffer = file_get_contents($path);
            $iv = str_pad($iv, 16, "\0");
            $cipher = openssl_encrypt($fileBuffer, "AES-256-CBC", $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
            $cipher64 = base64_encode($cipher);
            file_put_contents($path, $cipher64);
            exit;
        }
```

Comment: There are numerous compression algorithms and formats. You need to specify exactly which algorithm and format you are using to compress.

Comment: its a simple .zip but the .zip ext is removed from the file names so files are like example.jpg

Answer (score 0):

There is a builtin expression named *ZipArchive*. You can use this inside your function itself :

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$result = $zip->open('zipfile.zip');
```

After the decryption, you can put this.

Refer these doc as well -- [ZIPARCHIVE](http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.extractto.php) and [ZIPARCHIVE 2](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.zip.php)

Hope it helps.